# What version of httpclient is compatible with the Amazon SDK v 1.11.5?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, aws-sdk, nosuchmethoderror

I’m using the Amazon Java SDK, version 1.11.5 (I included the aws-java-sdk-1.11.5.jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory).  What version of the Apache httpclient library do I need to include that is compatible with this version of the AWS SDK?  I tried httpclient-4.3.4.jar, but I get the below error

```
15:34:25,366 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-34) UT005023: Exception handling request to /pluginwiris_engine/app/service: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:213)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:145)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:393)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:373)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:355)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:327)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:309)
```

Thanks for additional help, - Dave

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the source for the Java AWS SDK, under tag 1.11.5, [you can see the in the POM file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.11.5/pom.xml) they have specified the following:

```
<httpcomponents.httpclient.version>4.5.2</httpcomponents.httpclient.version>
```

So I'd say HTTP Client version 4.5.2 is compatible with the AWS SDK version 1.11.5. If you are using a dependency management tool like Maven you could always just let it pull in the version of HTTP Client specified the the AWS SDK.

[image: working combination of libraries]

Comment: I tried adding this jar but I still get the same error, was it all you needed to fix it?

Comment: @moondaisy you might have another version of httpclient somewhere in your classpath.

Comment: @LizBennett yes, in the end that was the problem the older versions where on the webapp folder in tomcat

Comment: Didn't work for me. I took out my http core and http client libs and it still wouldn't fly. I'm also using apache http fluent client, Maybe that's pulling in an incompatible version.

Comment: Thank you. Migrating from httpclient-4.5.13.jar to httpclient-4.5.2.jar fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the compile dependencies at [maven repo for aws-java-sdk-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.76)

You can see it's dependent on org.apache.httpcomponents » httpclient -- 4.5.2. Further check if you've all the [dependencies of httpclient-4.5.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2). You might be missing correct version of *`httpcore`*